# Send data WITHIN JSON via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to append another **home_address** within the array **address**.

```
  "fieldlist": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "street_name": "N. 10th",
      "address": [
        {
          "aid": 1,
          "home_address": "5801",
          "city": "Philadelphia"
        },
        {
          "aid": 2,
          "home_address": "5802",
          "city": "Philadelphia"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is the code gets added to end.

```
"fieldlist": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "street_name": "N. 10th",
      "address": [
        {
          "aid": 1,
          "home_address": "5801",
          "city": "Philadelphia"
        },
        {
          "aid": 2,
          "home_address": "5802",
          "city": "Philadelphia"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "aid": 4,
      "home_address": "5804",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my sample ajax code

```
var addnumber = {
                  "aid": 4,
                  "home_address": "5804"
            }

     $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/fieldlist',
                    data: JSON.stringify(addnumber),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json'

        });
```

Is there anyway I can append within the **address** `array` and not after the code block? Or should I change the structure of my `JSON`?

Comment: how are you adding it now?

Comment: Its not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: That ajax is activated on a click handler. I'm using json-server to host the file and the url is url: 'http://localhost:3000/fieldlist.

Answer (score 1):

Access the `fieldlist[0].address` and push into it instead of the `fieldlist`.

```js
var fieldlist = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "street_name": "N. 10th",
    "address": [
      {
        "aid": 1,
        "home_address": "5801",
        "city": "Philadelphia"
      },
      {
        "aid": 2,
        "home_address": "5802",
        "city": "Philadelphia"
      }
    ]
  }   
];

const newAddr = {"aid": 4, "home_address": "5804", "id": 2 };
fieldlist[0].address.push(newAddr);

console.log(fieldlist);
```

Comment: Forgot to add that the JSON is external. 
I'm using JSON-SERVER to host  the files that's why the code says
url:'http://localhost:3000/fieldlist.   
When i tried to post to url: 'http://localhost:3000/fieldlist/1  ....  I got an error

Comment: THANKS GUYS. And thanks Suren I think I figured it out. How silly am I, Json-server doesn't have a route to post to fieldlist/1.  Thanks to your post, I would have never seen that. Okay I'm gonna close this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I think I figured it out. I'm new to ajax, sorry. First off... I have to use a PUT request. I thought there was only post. 2nd, I have to use the correct route to the json url. I was lost until I posted this so thanks for the swift responses.